# php function - how to make dynamic with a query

Tags: php

How can I take a function which creates a metabox with a dropdown of hard coded values ("Hard", Soft" and "None") and make it create the metabox dynamically according to a given array of strings?

Original function:

```html
function your_prefix_product_fields( $meta_boxes )
{
 $meta_boxes[] = array(
  'title'  => __( 'Product Fields', 'your-prefix' ),
                'post_types' => array(
                    'product',
                ),
  'fields' => array(
           array(
    'name'        => __( 'Package', 'test' ),
    'id'          => 'package',
    'type'        => 'select',
    'clone'       => false,
    'options'     => array(
     'Soft' => __( 'Soft', 'test' ),
                    'Hard' => __( 'Hard', 'test' ),
     'None' => __( 'None', 'test' ),
    ),
    'multiple'    => true,
    'std'         => 'none',
    'placeholder' => __( 'Select Package', 'test' ),
   ),
  )
 );
return $meta_boxes;
}
```

I have the array: `["Hard", "Soft", "None"]`

EDIT:
I thought more about my question and perhaps I can make it more clear:

What I want to do is create this array dynamically from a query output:

```
'options'     => array(
                        'Soft' => __( 'Soft', 'test' ),
                        'Hard' => __( 'Hard', 'test' ),
                        'None' => __( 'None', 'test' ),
                    ),
```

Additional Questions:

1) If I can create the 'options array' manually, can I write something like:

```
'options'     => $packages,
```

given that I was able to create the array packages so that it will look like:

```
array(
                        'Soft' => __( 'Soft', 'test' ),
                        'Hard' => __( 'Hard', 'test' ),
                        'None' => __( 'None', 'test' ),
                    ),
```

2) How can I create this type of array? Is it a hash map?

I tried something like:

```
$packages['Soft'] = ('Soft', 'test');
```

With no luck... What is the syntax for it?

Comment: Can you explain at a high level what you are trying to do? Maybe this will give some clarity as the the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I have a combobox in WP admin that lets me choose values from hard coded value list.
I'd like to make that list dynamic (get the values from a table in mysql).

Comment: where is your mysql code?

Comment: @Kiyan it's just a simple query for posts.

Comment: I need to know how you get your data from data base and it structure, so i can gave you exact code

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly, it sounds like you already have a meta box up and working, but you are trying to give it a variable list of options for the drop-down.

The confusion here seems to be on the syntax for the `'options'` array. It's important to realize the `__($param1, $param2)` is simply a translate function defined by wordpress for use in localization. It will return a sting that is the translation of the the first parameter (a string) based on the domain (second parameter). More info here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2.

That said, you were on the right track, but you would want `$packages` to be something like this:

```
$packages = array(
    'Soft' => $val1,
    'Hard' => $val2,
    'None' => $val3
)
```

Where the three variables are whatever string you want. Then you should just be able to pass `$packages` as another argument to the function and set it as the value of `options` like you were thinking. Additionally, if you need translation and want to use the double underscore method, you should be able to call the function when you are creating your array. Or you could just loop through the array within `your_prefix_product_fields` before setting as the `'options'`:

```
foreach ($packages as $key => $opt)
    $packages[$key] = __($opt, 'test');
```